# First launch help form - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-ce, helper

I want to implement a simple help form to appear once the application has been installed and first launched, I just wanted to throw this question on here to see if anyone has came across a simple means of implementing this.

The way i'm currently thinking of is, by adding a simple table in my SQL CE database where a boolean value will be changed once the application has been launched more than once but i'm thinking this might be an unnecessary call to the database and a waste of code.

Any opinions on this matter will be greatly appreciated.

.net Framework 4.0
C# Windows form.

Comment: Keep track of launch state in `app.config or registry` instead of DB. If launched once update the state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say if you've already got an SQL CE database, then that's an appropriate place to store that.

As an alternative, if you want something really simple I've done this in the past:

```
if(!File.Exists("dontshowhelp.txt"))
{
   ShowMyDialog();
   File.CreateText("dontshowhelp.txt");
}
```

I like the above method because when you do updates or upgrades to the program, as long as you keep the same folder structure that kind of file wont be touched by an installer/uninstaller and so the setting "persists".

Then of course there's always the registry you can set a simple DWORD value in a similar fashion.

Comment: I like your second method as this is a little personal project that I've just continued work on which came about from uni. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know applications usually deal with this in a number of ways:

- A value in the registry
- A value in a .config file
- A serialised object (usually stored as XML)

or a value in a database like you suggest.

The advantage of a .config file is the ease of changing the value back (in case the user wanted to see the help again)

Comment: I'd appreciated a comment from the -1 please.

Comment: +1 - Of these, given that this feature is most important immediately after installation, I would go with the method least likely to fail. That would be config file in my opinion, or a separate file (like xml) written to the location Windows guarantees your app will have write access to. Any sort of database solution would be my last choice.

Comment: @hatchet - True, a db seems a bit overkill for a simple value

Answer (score 0):

I would use a simple xml document instead.  Perhaps just a serialized POCO object that was loaded when the application was started.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I've implemented this feature using one of the above methods for now, out of interest what is a POCO object? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you might consider is using a "preference" file that sits on the hard drive.

If the file doesn't exist, then create the file using defaults.  As a default, show the help form.  You can include on that help form a checkbox for "Do not show this form on startup", which can be one of the settings in your configuration.

If the file exists, read in the settings and determine if the user wants to see the help on future startups.

Your file can be a simple serialization of a `UserPreference` object, XML, or a custom formatting file that you read in and interpret.